# How to remove two duplicate column

Tags: mysql

i have some table like:
[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a648b/3)

I want this table to select only the following values(remove duplicates):
`from` | `to`
46  0
46  18
46  50
46  39
**46    11**
46  12
46  56

i use DISTINCT keyword,but this return folowing values:

46  0
46  18
46  50
46  39
**46    11

11  46**
46  12
46  56

please help me

Comment: Please show the query that you are using and give the tables names. If possible an http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Comment: @MaciejSz not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: It is not quite clear. Is `from` and `to` in your example two different tables or two columns of one table?

Comment: @AlexanderMyshov two columns of the same table as far as i can see.

Comment: from and two are two columns of one table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN TableName b
          ON a.from = b.to
             AND a.to = b.from
WHERE   a.from < b.from
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25888/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, it seems not so ideal, but it works:

```
select distinct pm.`from`, pm.`to`
from `tsk_private_message` pm
left join
    (select distinct pm.`from`, pm.`to`
     from `tsk_private_message` pm
         inner join `tsk_private_message` pm2
         on (pm.`to` = pm2.`from`) and (pm2.`to` <> pm.`from`)) a
     using (`from`, `to`)
where a.`from` is null;
```

In this query I just search unnecessary rows among these conversations via subquery:

```
select distinct pm.`from`, pm.`to`
from `tsk_private_message` pm
    inner join `tsk_private_message` pm2
    on (pm.`to` = pm2.`from`) and (pm2.`to` <> pm.`from`)) a
using (`from`, `to`)
```

and "subtract" this result from main table.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ef4/12)