# How to properly exclude rows with references to each other?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

This question is based on the not very trivial question [How to remove two duplicate column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441947/how-to-remove-two-duplicate-column). I already suggested solution on that question, but I think there is some more suitable and elegant solution than mine.

There is some table of private messages with columns `msg_id`, `from`, `to`.

And we have this data in it:

```
msg_id from   to
----------------
1      46     0
2      46     18
3      46     50
4      46     39
5      46     11  
6      11     46
7      46     12
8      46     56
9      46     11
```

We need to exclude rows with the conversations, in which there are more than one message (like rows with `msg_id = 5`, `6` and `9`) and in the same time we need to leave first row in output among these rows. In general output should be like this (note: without `msg_id = 6` and `msg_id = 9`):

```
msg_id from   to
----------------
1      46     0
2      46     18
3      46     50
4      46     39
5      46     11  
7      46     12
8      46     56
```

My solution is:

```
select distinct pm.`from`, pm.`to`
from `tsk_private_message` pm
left join
    (select distinct pm.`from`, pm.`to`
     from `tsk_private_message` pm
     inner join `tsk_private_message` pm2
     on (pm.`to` = pm2.`from`) and (pm2.`to` <> pm.`from`)) a
     using (`from`, `to`)
where a.`from` is null;
```

I just search unnecessary rows among these conversations via subquery and "subtract" result from the main table.  What do you think? Is there more elegant and more simple solution? I just really don't like this tricky code.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ef4/12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT mx.msg_id, pm.ffrom, pm.tto
FROM tsk_private_message pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tsk_private_message nx1
    WHERE nx1.ffrom = pm.ffrom AND nx1.tto = pm.tto
    AND nx1.msg_id < pm.msg_id
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM tsk_private_message nx2
    WHERE nx2.ffrom = pm.tto AND nx2.tto = pm.ffrom
    AND nx2.msg_id < pm.msg_id
    );
```

Note: I renamed the `to` and `from` columns to `tto` and `ffrom`, because **to** and **from** both are keywords in SQL and I don't like quoting identifiers.

Extra: [sqlfiddle (courtesy of Alexander Myshov)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ef4/20)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  tsk_private_message INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) min_id
    FROM tsk_private_message
    GROUP BY
      LEAST(`from`, `to`),
      GREATEST(`from`, `to`)) min_msg
  ON tsk_private_message.id = min_msg.min_id
ORDER BY
  id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81ef4/15).